# Scrapy Fetch command is not found when i am writing the scrapy command in jupyter lab instead of scrapy shell or cmd

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, jupyter-notebook, fetch

My Code

```
!scrapy fetch('http://www.biztech2go.com/')
```

Output error

```
Scrapy 2.3.0 - project: project1 

Unknown command: fetch('http://www.biztech2go.com/')

Use "scrapy" to see available commands
```

My code

```
fetch('http://www.biztech2go.com/')
```

Output Error

```
'fetch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this without brackets:

```
!scrapy fetch "http://www.biztech2go.com/"
```